# not able to create new users in mysql workbench but root user works fine

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I reinstalled Mysql multiple times but when I try to create a user for example "Test" I get this error

[image]

The root user logins fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
I logged in as root user and then on the left pane under "Navigator" there is "Users and privileges". Select that and then click "Add account". Fill in the details and then come back to home page of the mysql workbench. There you create a new connection and name it whatever you like and then use the username and password you used while adding the account.